# Deploy Code First Part II - Revised

Tags: deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I now understand the why the database initalizer is a no-go on my production server.  However, I am unable to find a step-by-step approach to deploying my project.

- Should I just copy the SQL create script from my test server to my production box?
- I assume I should remove the setInitializer from the Global.asax

Are there any other steps?  Am I way off track?

{EDIT}

I wish I could add more context.  My original question is here [Deploy Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573868/deploy-entity-framework-code-first).  This is my first MVC project and my first code first project.

I am just at a stage where I am ready to deploy it to my production server, but I am not sure what steps are involved.

I am simply looking for some links or steps to move my code from my test server to my live site.

Comment: There is a _lot_ of context missing from this question.  If this is part of your previous question, why not edit that question to include this content?  If this is a new question spawned from the previous one, you're going to have to provide context here for this one to make any sense.  Any one question (and its answer(s)) should be wholly complete in and of itself.

Comment: I added a similar comment to your other question.  A good way I found in deploying a Code First model is to use a Visual Studio Database Project.  I blogged about it here: http://kingdango.com/blog/2011/12/a-simple-solution-for-deploying-code-first-model/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a new database using your initialisers locally. then to detach this newly created database and to re-attach it to the production sql server ?

this would ensure that you have everything working in a fresh new database.

or you could use `Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio` to generate your database scripts and run them on the remote server. You may also want to look into `SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio`

There also exists tools from many vendors which enable you to generate the databse scripts.

Edit :

You will need to adjust your connection strings to point to the new database location with apropriate user and password. other wise, there isn't much else to do. As long as your databse schema matches the mappings found in your EF 4.1 Code First Model, this will work.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre!  Do I need to worry about connection strings or anything else?  If that is all I need to do I am a happy camper.